# Can Optaplanner manage various components needed for a reservation?

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

The project I am working on has multiple components of differing types. A user makes a reservation, and our Spring Boot server has to figure out when the components requested by the user will be available over the next 30 days (intervals of 1 minute).

If the server has to check that a bunch of components are available at a certain time, can Optaplanner pick out all the components for this one reservation ?

I'm kind of confused because the website briefly shows an "Equipment Scheduling" picture at the beginning of the documentation, but then I don't see any sort of thorough example relating specifically to equipment scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest challenge for OptaPlanner newcomers is to create a good model for their planning problem, especially if there is no example near it. Some tips:

1. Read the "domain modeling guide" in the docs (or [see this video about it](https://youtu.be/0uAoWU8m0pE)).
2. Take a look at the cheaptime example in optaplanner-examples (not optaplanner-quickstarts). That sounds a bit similar to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Watching your talk from September helped me understand the framework a bit better.

Comment: Sent you a message on Twitter regarding a project I'm working on for the Canadian Space Agency. Would love to be able to communicate with you privately to get some more help.